# Change Package Identity Name,Publisher & ReSign appxbundle

Tags: uwp, windows-10-universal, windows-10-desktop, signtool, makeappx

What is the possibility of changing the applications Package Identity Name & Publisher for an existing appxbundle file and then re-sign the same with another certificate?

We have a requirement where we will receive a pre-signed application.appxbundle file, and we need to change the application's Package Identity Name & Publisher and the re-sign the application with another certificate.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What is the possibility of changing the applications Package Identity Name & Publisher for an existing appxbundle file and then re-sign the same with another certificate?

No, this is not possible. There might be security issues that if a signed package could be re-signed by other certificates.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can expand the file (rename to `.zip` first), extract the files, update the `AppManifest.xml` file with the new publisher info and then repackage with `makeappx` and re-sign.